NextJs/React : how to prevent click event when UIs are overlayed?
I can't figure out with NextJs/React how to prevent click event when UIs are layered.
But I am sure it's doable.
Here is the working example:
This is a UI from Vercel and I believe it's made of NextJs.


When ... is clicked button => show a floating menu UI
When #89 is clicked redirect to my github page
When background (anywhere in the box UI) is clicked => redirect to my app

In my case, When 1 or 2 is clicked, 3 always executed because of the click event emitting. I'd like to prevent 3 while 1 or 2 is clicked. The Vercel website is the perfect example.
I thought I can solve by e.preventdefault() or anything prevent event capturing & bubbling but it doesn't work.
Does anyone knows the Vercel github (is this public?) or how to solve this with NextJs/React?

For 1 and 2 you can add e.stopPropagation()

Thanks, I was testing with preventdefault() in a totally wrong place.
